# Installation fails on "Installing database schema"

Tags: installation, magento-2.0, database-schema

When installing Magento 2.0, the "Customize your store" page shows there is an error (although there are no details under the "show details" link). It will proceed past this point, however when installing it fails at 0%, suggests I check the console log, which only shows the following:

> Starting Magento installation:
>   File permissions check...
>
> Enabling Maintenance Mode...
>
> Installing deployment configuration...
>
> Installing database schema:

Any advice from anyone who has installed this previously? I'm using a CentOS box, with php 5.6.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely not going to help you, but it might help others.  I experienced this problem when php `max_execution_time` and `memory_limit` were set too low.  I set mine to `360` and `2048M` respectively.  This resolved the issue and greatly improved my magento2 performance as well.

Answer (score 0):

Old but... you can find the logs under your

> webserver/magentoInstallation/var/log

They have more details about your error.

If you tried to install on a **WAMP** Webserver you will find them under

`WAMPFolder/www/yourmagentoinstallation/var/log`